# How to manually trigger BootStrap Validation on blur of a text input event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap validation for my Application .

Incase if user enters "abc" under text input how to show a validation message , Entered value is not allowed

This is my code

```
$('#taginsertform').bootstrapValidator(
{
        feedbackIcons:
        {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields:
        {
                recipientname:
                {
                        feedbackIcons: 'false',
                        validators:
                        {
                                notEmpty:
                                {
                                        message: 'Reciepnt Name cannot be empty'
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}).on('success.form.bv', function(e)
{
        e.preventDefault();
        addTagSbmt();
});

function addTagSbmt()
{
   $('#taginsertform').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
        $('.closemodal').trigger('click');

        return false;
}
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function()
{
        $('#taginsertform').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
});


$( "#recipientname" ).blur(function() {

  var recipientnameval = $("#recipientname").val();

  recipientnameval = recipientnameval.toLowerCase();

  if(recipientnameval==='abc')
  {
  alert(recipientnameval);
  // fire bootstrap valdation as invalid data 
  }

});
```

In the below jsfiddle , upon entering abc under text input how can i show a message ?
http://jsfiddle.net/xmrxbL9f/97/

Answer (score 8):

In short, no there is no built in bootstrap functionality to do the validation.

Bootstrap simply provides styles to the default [HTML input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp), [HTML input attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) and [JavaScript constraints validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) functionality. In order to validate an `element` we call the `checkValidity()` JavaScript method.

If you are following the [BootStrap Form Validation documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#custom-styles) then we can accomplish an `onblur` event validation with the following snippet.

```
$(function () { // jQuery ready
    // On blur validation listener for form elements
    $('.needs-validation').find('input,select,textarea').on('focusout', function () {
        // check element validity and change class
        $(this).removeClass('is-valid is-invalid')
               .addClass(this.checkValidity() ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid');
    });
});
```

This example will set the `is-valid` or `is-invalid` class on the current element when it looses focus. Note we are assigning event listeners to all `input,select,textarea` in all forms with the class `needs-validation`.

If you wish to trigger a different type of notification the same can be applied.

nJoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can append the error div on blur. Try it if it matches your requirement.

```
 $( "#recipientname" ).blur(function() {

  var recipientnameval = $("#recipientname").val();

 recipientnameval = recipientnameval.toLowerCase();
 var errorDiv = "<div class='form-error alert alert-danger fade in'>Please Insert valid data<div>"
 if(recipientnameval==='abc')
  {
   $('.form-group').append(errorDiv);
  }else{
   $('.form-error').remove();
  }
});
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: rather than manually doing this is it possible to use built in methods from bootstrap for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the form as formId

```js
var formEl = $("#formId");

formEl.find('input,select,textarea').on('focusout', function () {

    var thisEl = $(this).parent();
    if(!thisEl.hasClass('was-validated')){
        thisEl.addClass('was-validated');
    }

});
```